# Asp.net Formview using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview

I have a formview that binds to an objectdatasource. Which the objectdatasource is getting its values from a list collection. There are few textbox controls I had to switch out for dropdownlist in order to implement the cascading dropdownlist. The values are populating fine the cascading dropdownlist works great however on insert I get this annoying unhelpful message

"Index was outside the bounds of the array." So I have been trying to figure this out and cant.

Assuming it is my dropdownlist causing the issue I have tried to add this code to the code behind as I am manually binding them so they do not have the Text='<%# Bind("GroupID") %>

```
  protected void formGroupInput_ItemInserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
{

    if (formGroupInput.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Insert)
    {
                  e.Values["ddlStartTime"] = ((DropDownList)((FormView)sender).FindControl("ddlStartTime")).SelectedItem;
       e.Values["ddlEndTime"] = ((DropDownList)((FormView)sender).FindControl("ddlEndTime")).SelectedItem;
       e.Values["ddlRoomName"] = ((DropDownList)((FormView)sender).FindControl("ddlRoomName")).SelectedItem;
       e.Values["ddlJackNumber"] = ((DropDownList)((FormView)sender).FindControl("ddlJackNumber")).SelectedItem;
       e.Values["ddlInternetType"] = ((DropDownList)((FormView)sender).FindControl("ddlInternetType")).SelectedItem;
    }

}
```

I am guessing it has something to do with this because when I tried to debug it by placing a breakpoint on my input method in my DLL it did not even reach that yet before it displayed the error.

Thanks

[image]

Code to Populate dropdownlist

```
  protected void formGroupInput_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    if (formGroupInput.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Insert)
    {
        DropDownList roomName = (DropDownList)(formGroupInput.Row.FindControl("ddlRoomName"));
        roomName.DataSource = getrooms.FetchRooms();
        roomName.DataTextField = "RoomName";
        roomName.DataValueField = "intRoom";
        roomName.DataBind();

       ****Same concept for other 2 dropdownlist ******


    }
}
```

Page Load I call this

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DropDownList startTime = (DropDownList)(formGroupInput.Row.FindControl("ddlStartTime"));


    if (startTime.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        startTime.Items.Add("12:00AM");
        startTime.Items.Add("12:30AM");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 11; i++)
        {
            startTime.Items.Add(i + ":00AM");
            startTime.Items.Add(i + ":15AM");
            startTime.Items.Add(i + ":30AM");
        }

        startTime.Items.Add("12:00PM");
        startTime.Items.Add("12:30PM");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 11; i++)
        {
            startTime.Items.Add(i + ":00PM");
            startTime.Items.Add(i + ":15PM");
            startTime.Items.Add(i + ":30PM");
        }
    }


    DropDownList endTime = (DropDownList)(formGroupInput.Row.FindControl("ddlEndTime"));

    if (endTime.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        Same As Above
    }
```

Comment: Do you know what method is throwing the exception?  Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Also, please post the code you're using to populate the dropdowns.

Comment: Have you tried putting breakpoints at the top and stepping-through each of your formGroupInput_ItemInsert* functions?

Comment: Wow! Did you really need to post all of that code? I bet you could reproduce the problem with much less code.

Comment: I guess not John but Ann Requested it my initial post I tried to only post what I thought was necessary but what do I know Thanks for taking the time to comment and no time to help have a nice day

Comment: Also yes tgolisch I did debug it and found that I was sending the value of my dropdownlist rather than the selected item so all that has been changed but the problem still exist

Comment: Ann requested "the code you're using to populate the dropdowns". One interpretation of that request is to post "all the code you're using to populate all of the dropdowns". Another interpretation would be to post enough code for us to see what the problem is and to help you resolve it.

Comment: Suggestion noted John...moving on if you care to help feel free.

Comment: Also from debugging I notice that my values seem to be fine but after the debugger leaves the Form_Inserting method it goes straight to my details class where I have public properties setup but it jumps straight to my default constructor and fails after that any ideas?

Comment: Could you post your ObjectDataSource tag? It appears to be a problem with an Int32 insert parameter.

Comment: <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="objGroupInput" runat="server" 
        SelectMethod="FetchGroups" TypeName="GroupManage.GrpDataOps" 
        DataObjectTypeName="GroupManage.Details" InsertMethod="InsertGroup">
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>

Comment: Nothing obvious seems to have jumped out to any of us.  Next two steps for me are 1) start adding try/catch blocks around everything and put breakpoints in the catch.  2) start commenting-out or removing stuff until it starts working again, then add stuff back-in till I isolate the problem.

Comment: The error message (graphic) says that the error is happening when you are doing an insert into your DataSourceView.  It seems to think you are referring to a DB column that doesn't exist.  Are you sure that all of your column names match exactly and exist in your current DSV?

Answer (score 0):

Just for visitors to this question in future. This happens if you have a Int32 parameter that is bound but has not been set in the formview so the value of the control is the empty string. The empty string causes a parsing error to Int32. In your ObjectDataSource control you need something like this:

```
<InsertParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="MyParameterName" Type="Int32" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
</InsertParameters>
```